# javascript chart API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts

I'm working on a executive dashboard where I will be displaying some tables and charts...  due to the n ature of the project I can't use any server side technology (don´t ask me why is a dumb policy I know), so I have to consume a webservice via ajax and get some arrays of data to my app. I´ve tried several API´s but all of them seem to have a limitation or something that kills it, unfortunately the corporate users rely on IE 7 and this can't be changed so I need a solution that wokrs perfectly on it. I already try google charts, graphael,bluff, flot, plotkit, jquery visualize and jqplot.

The only API that meets absolutely is highcharts, unfortunately it requires a commercial licence which management is unwilling to pay. Bluff charts get really weird when scaled to more than 800px, flot has a very limited API and the tooltips on multi axis dont work, plotkit and jquery visualize doesnt have tooltips and I couldnt find any good documentation on gpraphael, my best shot was Jqplot which was meeting all my needs until I tried to print it on paper, they print unaligned.. seems to be a problem with excanvas...

Are there any other alternative that has tooltips, doesnt require server side, is free and is printable on IE?

EDIT

I am open to a free Silverlight solution if there is one.

Comment: Try reading this question's answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163479/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-svg-in-ie7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just give you the list of chart-things, that i have bookmarked:

- http://www.highcharts.com/ ( this is not free lib, but it might be just what you need )
- http://www.jscharts.com/ ( also not a free thing )
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/
- http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/
- http://mootools.net/forge/p/milkchart
- http://www.jqplot.com/
- http://thejit.org/
- http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/
- http://dygraphs.com/
- http://www.globfx.com/ ( not javascript, afaik , and wants $$$ )

Comment: thanks, although I mentioned most of them at my post, and the ones I didn't aren't either free or they don't support printing on IE

Answer (score 2):

Check out Kendo UI's charting tools (uses SVG): http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/overview/index.html

Comment: just tried it, it doesn't works on IE.

Comment: works on IE for me - down to IE7

Comment: thats odd, are you using IE7 installation or IE 9 emulating 7 ? i'm using version 7.0.5